# How insert to MySQL many rows PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I'd like to send a lot of rows to mysql.
I have a php form that lists all the products (about 200). I don't know how to add all the items to the mysql database ...
Is a loop necessary?

```
<form method="POST" action=""; model_load('orderForm_model', 'sendOrder'); echo "">
    <div class="col-1">PLU</div>
    <div class="col-1">IL</div>
    <div class="col-2">OP</div>>";
    
    $orderStandardForm = $this->__db->execute("SELECT ID_product from product");

    foreach($orderStandardForm as $orderStandardForm_)
    {
    echo "  <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1"><input type="number" name="plu" value="{$orderStandardForm_['ID_produkt']}"></div>
                <div class="col-1"><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="decimal" id="input1" step="0.01" name="il" class="width100"></div>
                <div class="col-2"><input type="text" id="opisTxt_{$orderStandardForm_['ID_produkt']}" name="op" class="width100"></div>
            </div>";
    }
    echo "   <input class="btn btn-primary width100" type="submit" value="Send order">
</form>";
```

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-multiple-rows/

Comment: I think you may need to review the `<form ....>` line

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA Do I have to add all the rows to the array in such a solution?

Comment: Check the answer which I've posted of Sample Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
        <form method="POST" action=""; model_load('orderForm_model', 'sendOrder'); echo "">
        <div class="col-1">PLU</div>
        <div class="col-1">IL</div>
        <div class="col-2">OP</div>>";
        
        $orderStandardForm = $this->__db->execute("SELECT ID_product from product");

        foreach($orderStandardForm as $orderStandardForm_)
        {
        echo "  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1"><input type="number" name="plu[]" value="{$orderStandardForm_['ID_produkt']}"></div>
                    <div class="col-1"><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="decimal" id="input1" step="0.01" name="il[]" class="width100"></div>
                    <div class="col-2"><input type="text" id="opisTxt_{$orderStandardForm_['ID_produkt']}" name="op[]" class="width100"></div>
                </div>";
        }
        echo "   <input class="btn btn-primary width100" type="submit" value="Send order">
    </form>";
```

PHP save process:

```
        $plu_arr = $_POST["plu"];
    $il_arr = $_POST["il"];
    $op_arr = $_POST["op"];
    $row_index = 0;
    $row_arr = array();
    foreach($plu_arr as $plu_data){
       if(isset($il_arr[$row_index]) && $il_arr[$row_index] != ''){
        $row_arr[] = "('".$plu_data."','".$il_arr[$row_index]."','".$op_arr[$row_index]."')";
        }
        $row_index++;
    }

    $ins_qry = "INSERT INTO your_table_name (plu, il, op) VALUES ".implode(", ", $row_arr);
    $db_ins = $this->__db->execute($ins_qry);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work ... I added
if ($ ins_qry) header ('Refresh: 0; URL = 0');
I refresh the page but the database is empty ...
Maybe the problem is in a constant value ... In each line I have to add a constant that is the same for a given order ...
$ row_arr [] = "('". $ plu_data. "', '15000', '". $ il_arr [$ row_index]. "', '". $ op_arr [$ row_index]. "')";

Comment: Can you please show whole code of save process?

Comment: $selectNumberZam = $this->__db->execute("SELECT idOrder from orders;");
$selectNumberZam_ = $selectNumberZam[0]['$selectNumberZam'];
$plu_arr = $_POST["plu"];
$il_arr = $_POST["il"];
$op_arr = $_POST["op"];
$row_index = 0;
$row_arr = array();
foreach($plu_arr as $plu_data){
$row_arr[] = "('".$plu_data."','$selectNumberZam_','".$il_arr[$row_index]."','".$op_arr[$row_index]."')";
    $row_index++;
}
$ins_qry = "INSERT INTO productOrder (idProduct, idOrder, il, op) VALUES ".implode(", ", $row_arr);
$_SESSION['message'] = "Send!";
if($ins_qry) header('Refresh: 0;');

Comment: You need to add: $db_ins = $this->__db->execute($ins_qry);

Comment: It works! But it puts all items into the database instead of those where the client enters $il
Most of them are zeros

Comment: I've Updated the answer please check, Added isset and not empty condition into the foreach.

Comment: Like that?
foreach($plu_arr as $plu_data){
              if(isset($il_arr) and !empty($il_arr))
              {
                $row_arr[] = "('".$plu_data."','$selectNumberZam_','".$il_arr[$row_index]."','".$op_arr[$row_index]."')";
                $row_index++;
              }
          }

Comment: foreach($plu_arr as $plu_data){ 
        if(isset($il_arr[$row_index]) and !empty($il_arr[$row_index])) { 
            $row_arr[] = "('".$plu_data."','$selectNumberZam_','".$il_arr[$row_index]."','".$op_arr[$row_index]."')"; 
        } 
        $row_index++; 
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240125/discussion-between-k-turek-and-khimaji-valukiya).

Answer (score 1):

I’m having trouble understanding your question. Is that correct?

```
the code name="plu" change to name="plu[]"

the code name="il" change to name="il[]"

the code name="op" change to name="op[]"
```

Comment: I have a form of 200 items in the format: plu, il, op.
and I need to save items in (isset ($ il)) to the database:
values (plu, il, op), (plu, il, op), (plu, il, op), (plu, il, op), ....